# primefaces 5.0 gmap widget error

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using **Primefaces v5.0** and encountered the error, - "Uncaught ReferenceError: mapWidget is not defined", while accessing **p:gmap** widget in javascript.

The js code snippet where the request to the widget "mapWidget" is made:

```
mapWidget.getMap().setCenter(latlng);
```

In PF4 all works okay. Is it the 5.0 bug or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you add it to your page? As in, `<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true|false" type="text/javascript"></script>` is present on the page? Does your map have all 4 four necessary attributes? `center`, `zoom`, `style`, and `type` ?

Comment: yes I did. As I mentioned, the map and its widget are working properly under PrimeFaces v4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to PrimeFaces 5.0 documentation the following code fragment should work:

```
PF('yourWidgetVar').getMap().setCenter(latlng);
```